# Single Instance Stored Procedure call

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures

Is there any way that I can make sure that a stored procedure completely finishes before another instance of it is started?

I have to do 3 things in the procedure and if two instances are running at the same time it will mess up a boundary case.

Example: Count rows, if < X insert a row, return calculated Y

if multiple instances of the stored proc can run at the same time I could go past my X target. Chance is small, but its there.

DB we're using is MYSQL5, but also wondering for MSSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transactions. Check row count afterwards and roll back if it's gone over.

Comment: I don't see how this would solve my problem.  Would this not also leave the ability for both now to roll back at the same time? I'm probably missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try leveraging [locking reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to allow concurrency to ensure that you're operating as a singleton.

NOTE: This will block all other calls and they will execute serially. Make sure this is the behavior you're after.